# How to deal with memory by calling the Dispose(),and Destory() method correctly?

Tags: c#, memory, mono, gtk3, gtk#

I'm learning GTKSharp library.
When I dispose my widget ,i found it cannot free all my memory.
I test by this demo that I write. One button for add more button in the Vbox, and one to remove them
When I press the "removeButton",it didn't release as I expected ,so is the "addbutton",it seems my memory keep going high when I pressed them more. when i check it by VS2022 I saw there are toggleref still there.
I read the github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp/issues/82
I saw this issue is closed but I didn't figure it out.
I think I didn't use the library correctly, can someone help me? or tell me how to free my memory cottectly. That would help me a lot!

```
using Gtk;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MainForm : Window
{
    private VBox mainBox;
    private HButtonBox buttonBox;
    private ScrolledWindow scrolledWindow;
    private VBox container;
    private Button addButton;
    private Button removeButton;

    private List<Button> createdButtons = new List<Button>();

    public MainForm() : base("GTK# Demo")
    {
        SetDefaultSize(400, 300);
        DeleteEvent += OnMainWindowDelete;

        mainBox = new VBox();

        buttonBox = new HButtonBox();
        addButton = new Button("Add Buttons");
        removeButton = new Button("Remove Buttons");
        addButton.Clicked += OnAddButtonClicked;
        removeButton.Clicked += OnRemoveButtonClicked;

        buttonBox.Add(addButton);
        buttonBox.Add(removeButton);

        scrolledWindow = new ScrolledWindow();
        scrolledWindow.SetPolicy(PolicyType.Automatic, PolicyType.Automatic);

        container = new VBox();
        scrolledWindow.Add(container);

        mainBox.PackStart(buttonBox, false, false, 5);
        mainBox.PackStart(scrolledWindow, true, true, 5);

        Add(mainBox);
    }

    private void OnAddButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (var button in createdButtons)
        {
            container.Remove(button);
            button.Destroy();
        }
        createdButtons.Clear();


        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            Button newButton = new Button($"button{i}");
            container.Add(newButton);
            newButton.Show();
            createdButtons.Add(newButton);
        }
    }

    private void OnRemoveButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (var button in createdButtons)
        {
            container.Remove(button);
            button.Destroy();
        }
        createdButtons.Clear();

        GC.Collect(); 
    }

    private void OnMainWindowDelete(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```

I really need someone can tell me how to handle the memory management.
Or i think i didn't use the

```
destory()
```

```
dispose()
```

correctly. I cannot found this part of tutorial about dispose()or destory().